# Random non-intersecting circles in the plane

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-probability

If I give a finite region of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and place $k$ circles of radius $r(k)$ uniformly at random inside, are there any known results for the probability that the circles do not overlap? Equivalently, I want the probability that the area covered by the circles is $k\pi r(k)^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to asking what the distribution of minimal interpoint distance is. This is addressed in a number of places, in particular, in [this article of Tanagawa, Mochizuki, Tanaka, 1992.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/TMT.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, could this stuff be generalized if my points where say in a square or circle?

Comment: @PavanSangha Yes, these sorts of questions have been done in convex polygons - generalization is usually not trivial, but not super hard (and for large $k,$ the results are usually more or less independent of the enclosing shape).

Comment: Brilliant, do you have any links to papers?

Comment: For large $n,$ this reduces to a local question, so the distance will be, roughly a function of the area of the region and the number of points. Just google "Poisson point process".

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate a little more?